# How to change "pathInfo" of HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

I am afraid to ask a strange question but I want to change "pathInfo" of HttpServletRequest at a handler method of a Controller. Please take look at below.

I know I can get "pathInfo" by using getPathInfo(). However. I don't know how to set up the pathInfo. Is it possible ? Any help will be appreciated

```
@RequestMapping(value = "show1" method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show1(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    // I want to set up "PathInfo" but this kind of methods are not provided 
    //request.setPathInfo("/show2");

    // I thought that BeanUtils.copy may be available.. but no ideas.

    // I have to call show2() with the same request object
    return show2(model, request);
}

// I am not allowed to edit this method
private String show2(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    // I hope to display "http://localhost:8080/contextroot/show2"
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());

    return "complete";
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I don't think it's a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @adarshr Thank you for your comment. Exactly I know this is a not good way but I have to an unmodifiable method in my work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set these values.

The only option is to create a wrapper for your request, something like this:

```
return show2(model, new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
    public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
        return new StringBuffer(
            super.getRequestURL().toString().replaceFirst("/show1$", "/show2"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks! It worked without any modification to the show2() ! But why? I'v never seen such the notation... Does it mean that getRequestURL() is replaced?

Comment: and anybody. I want to know the notation deeply. Could you tell me what is the name. I will google.

Comment: @yusaku: It's an anonymous inner class being created that extends `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and overrides one of its methods. `HttpServletRequestWrapper` is used for convenient implementation of the Proxy pattern for `HttpServletRequest`s.

Comment: "anonymous inner class" .. "overrides one of its methods".. Great! very userful! I appreciate it! "Proxy pattern" .. I've heard that a little. I will check it out too.

Answer (score 1):

Path Info is set by the browser (client) when it requests a certain URL.